# Arch DVD colours

Tags: arch-linux, graphics, dvd

On my Arch machine, I wanted to play the DVD Skyfall. It opened with VLC, and everything worked, except that everything was a bit greenish. Why is that happening? Dragon player isn't better either. The odd thing is that, when I tested other DVDs, it worked. Skyfall also had no problems on my PowerBook, with Mac OS 10.5. This is a bit of an odd question, but I don't understand why that should happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `mplayer` (or a frontend like `smplayer`).

The issue is related to OpenGL hardware GPU accleration [reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2158707)

It would be helpful to know which GPU you have. Arch recently enabled SNA acceleration by default for Intel GPUs. If it's an older GPU (intel/nvidia/ati) it likely doesn't have support, so disable hw accel.

Comment: I've got an i3 CPU with a h61 chipset. Smplayer didn't help.

Comment: Based on that limited info, you either have Intel HD2000, HD3000, or maybe even using an Nvidia or AMD GPU. Regardless see if [UXA acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Choose_acceleration_method) fixes the issue. And make sure you have the latest `xf86-video-intel` driver package installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems and it turned out it depended on which output module you have selected. For example, in `vlc`:

[image]

I would guess the same applies to the other programs. Try `Xvideo` and `X11 video` first but depending on your setup,it may be one of the others as well. Also, `vlc` sometimes needs to be restarted for the settings to take effect.